# python dictionary update in Monte Carlo algorithm

Tags: python, dictionary, montecarlo

I am trying to write a Monte Carlo code where I optimize the elements in a dictionary. For example, I define my original dictionary as

```
A = {}
A[1] = ['a','b','c']
A[2] = ['d','e','f']
```

This results in

```
>>> A
{1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['d', 'e', 'f']}
```

Now say that a trial move in my Monte Carlo is to take a random element 'a' from A[1] and put it in A[2]. However, I want to keep my original dictionary. So I first create a new dictionary:

```
B = A
```

And then in B I make the desired changes

```
B[1].remove('a')
B[2].append('a')
```

That results in the modified dictionary that I wanted to obtain:

```
>>> B
{1: ['b', 'c'], 2: ['d', 'e', 'f', 'a']}
```

However this has also changed my original dictionary A, which I did want to backup.

```
>>> A
{1: ['b', 'c'], 2: ['d', 'e', 'f', 'a']}
```

Is there any way that I can do this?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you think `B = A` makes a copy of the dictionary?

Comment: Actually the way a see it is that B = A makes a copy of A and assign it to B, but A is a reference to the dictionary (and its content consists of references to lists). I hope I've been useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a deep copy of the dictionary:

```
import copy
B = copy.deepcopy(A)
```

If you don't do this, the array references are shared between the dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to do a shallow copy of the dictionaries:

```
A = {}
A[3] = 2
C = A.copy()
C[3] = 3
print C[3],A[3]
```

output: 3,2

but this won't work in your specific case, since your keys are indeed references to mutable objects, in your case either you know how the objects work and implement your copy:

```
B = {}
for i in A.keys():
    B[i] = []
    B[i].extend(A[i])
B[1].remove('a')
B[2].append('a')
```

or you make a deepcopy(). 
I don't like a lot the latter solution since I cannot control how the deep copy actually works. http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html

Comment: Try the following to get the difference between copying the reference to the dict and copying the dictionary: A = {0:3,1:4,2:3}; B = A; C = A.copy(); B[2] = 4; print A[2],B[2],C[2].